# wxpython treelistctrl crashes on windows7

Tags: wxpython

I have an old application which is based in python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 and pyInstaller 2.0. I have some struggles on wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl. When I try to test the exe (built using pyInstaller) on Windows 7 (I know it's old)the application crashes (in terms of windows crash).

The code is quite simple and has been taken from the demo of wxPython:

```
    self.tree = gizmos.TreeListCtrl(self, -1, style =
                                    wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE |
                                    wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT
                                    #| wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS
                                    #| wx.TR_TWIST_BUTTONS
                                    #| wx.TR_ROW_LINES
                                    #| wx.TR_COLUMN_LINES
                                    #| wx.TR_NO_LINES 
                                    | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT
                               )

    self.tree.AddColumn('')
   
    for col, date in enumerate(sales):
        self.tree.AddColumn(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
        
    
    self.tree.SetMainColumn(0)       
    self.tree.SetColumnWidth(0, 400)          
    root = self.tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")

    parent = root

    idx = 1
    for row in range(h):
        idx = idx + 1
        row_title = str(self.matrix[0][row])
        if row_title.startswith('##END'):
            parent = root 

        elif row_title.startswith('##'):
            row_title = row_title.replace('##', '')
            
            parent = self.tree.AppendItem(root, row_title)
   
            idx = 1

        elif parent:             
            item = self.tree.AppendItem(parent, row_title) 
  

    self.tree.ExpandAll(root) 
    self.Layout()
```

If I try to remove the line:

```
            item = self.tree.AppendItem(parent, row_title)
```

the code runs fine I have no crash. But I need it to populate the kids of every parent node. Do I need specific DLL to use the gizmos.TreeListCtrl ?

by using "dependency walker" tool it looks like the windows error is the following:

00:00:36.317: Second chance exception 0xC0000005 (Access Violation) occurred in "c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\COMCTL32.DLL" at address 0x737D8A66 by thread 1.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the issue by using [GroupListView](https://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/groupListView.html) instead of TreeListCtrl